# Why does this program not run in Cursive?

Tags: clojure

It does neither compile nor run in Cursive:

```
(ns test)
(defn -main "This should be pretty simple."
  []
  (javax.swing.JOptionPane/showMessageDialog nil "Hello World"))
```

The file is named test.clj. It is the only file in the whole project. 
I get to see the green arrow on the left side, but when I click it - it says `Nothing here`. When I try to run it - I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main
```

Comment: Maybe show the error message?

Comment: I was able to compile and run your example, in Cursive and command line, and both with and without Leiningen.

Comment: Do you specify the namespace for `-main` in your Run Configuration? Do you have other project files in addition to this `test` namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to create a specific clojure module/project in Cursive. You cannot just put a clojure file and hope, that it will get compiled and executed.

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that Intellij IDEA is trying to run [clojure.main](https://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main).

To run your own `-main`, create a [Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) for a Clojure Application, where you specify the namespace as `test`. The option to select in the Run Configuration is "Run -main from Clojure namespace".

Consider using a build tool, such as [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/), for managing your build and running a REPL.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly the way I used to start this program. Maybe it needs some extra software which is not installed on my system? I used homebrew to install clojure.

Comment: @MatthiasDanetzky Leiningen is THE build tool for Clojure. I suggest you use that.